# attempt to display details in another Activity "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0"

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, adapter

I'm trying to use OnItemClick to display details in a user profile page and I still have this error:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
        at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
        at fr.ousoft.suiviemedsbox.ScrollingActivity.OnItemClick(**ScrollingActivity.java:102**)
        at fr.ousoft.suiviemedsbox.UsersAdapter$AdapterVH$1.onClick(**UsersAdapter.java:115**)
```

Here is my Activity code

```
    public class ScrollingActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements UsersAdapter.OnItemClickListener {

    public static final String EXTRA_CREATOR_NOM = "Nom";
    public static final String EXTRA_CREATOR_PRENOM = "Prenom";
    public static final String EXTRA_CREATOR_TEL = "Tel";
    public static final String EXTRA_CREATOR_EMAIL = "Email";
    public static final String EXTRA_CREATOR_ETABLISSEMENT = "Etablissement";
    public static final String EXTRA_CREATOR_TYPE = "Type";
    public static final String EXTRA_CREATOR_ACTIVE = "Active";

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    ApiInterface apiInterface;
    UsersAdapter usersAdapter;
    ArrayList<User> mListe = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scrolling);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        CollapsingToolbarLayout toolBarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_layout);
        toolBarLayout.setTitle(getTitle());

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(ScrollingActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewList);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));

        usersAdapter = new UsersAdapter();

        fetchUsers();
    }

    public void fetchUsers(){
        apiInterface = ApiClient.getRetrofitInstance().create(ApiInterface.class);
        Call<List<User>> call = apiInterface.getAllUsers();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<User>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<User>> call, Response<List<User>> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()){
                    List<User> users = response.body();
                    usersAdapter.setData(users);
                    usersAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(ScrollingActivity.this);

                    recyclerView.setAdapter(usersAdapter);

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<User>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("success", t.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void OnItemClick(int position) {
        Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this,DetailActivity.class);
        User clickedUser = mListe.get(position);

        detailIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_CREATOR_NOM, clickedUser.getNom());
        detailIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_CREATOR_PRENOM, clickedUser.getPrenom());
        detailIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_CREATOR_TEL, clickedUser.getTel());
        detailIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_CREATOR_EMAIL, clickedUser.getEmail());
        detailIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_CREATOR_ETABLISSEMENT, clickedUser.getEtablissement());
        detailIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_CREATOR_TYPE, clickedUser.getType());
        detailIntent.putExtra(EXTRA_CREATOR_ACTIVE, clickedUser.getActive());

        startActivity(detailIntent);
    }
}
```

Adapter:

```
    public class UsersAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UsersAdapter.AdapterVH>{


    private List<User> userList;
    private Context context;
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void OnItemClick(int position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener){
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public UsersAdapter(){
    }

    public void setData(List<User> userList){
        this.userList = userList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public AdapterVH onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        context = parent.getContext();
        return new UsersAdapter.AdapterVH(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_list,parent,false));
    }

    @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull AdapterVH holder, int position) {
        User user = userList.get(position);

        String nom = user.getNom();
        String email = user.getEmail();
        String etab = user.getEtablissement();
        String active = user.getActive();
        String prenom = user.getPrenom();

        holder.txtNom.setText(nom);
        if (nom == null) {
            holder.txtNom.setText("Aucun Nom");
        }
        holder.txtEmail.setText(email);
        if (email == null) {
            holder.txtEmail.setText("Aucun Email");
        }
        holder.txtEttab.setText(etab);
        if (etab == null) {
            holder.txtEttab.setText("Aucun Etablissement");
        }
        holder.txtPrenom.setText(prenom);
        if (prenom == null) {
            holder.txtPrenom.setText("Aucun Prenom");
        }
        if (active == null) {
            holder.ActiveDesactive.setText(R.string.desact);
        }else {
            holder.ActiveDesactive.setText(R.string.activ);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return userList.size();
    }


    public class AdapterVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView txtNom;
        TextView txtPrenom;
        TextView txtEmail;
        TextView txtEttab;
        Button ActiveDesactive;

        public AdapterVH(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            txtNom = itemView.findViewById(R.id.NomUser);
            txtPrenom = itemView.findViewById(R.id.PrenomUser);
            txtEmail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.EmailUser);
            txtEttab = itemView.findViewById(R.id.EtabUser);
            ActiveDesactive = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ActiveDesavtive);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (mListener != null){
                        int positions = getAdapterPosition();
                        if (positions != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION){
                            mListener.OnItemClick(positions);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never fill `mListe` with any content. If you search for `mListe.` the only match you get is `mListe.get`. You have no invocations of `mListe.add` or `mListe.addAll`. What you do instead is set a list from a response directly into the adapter:

```
if (response.isSuccessful()){
    // Here is the error
    List<User> users = response.body();
    
    usersAdapter.setData(users);
    usersAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(ScrollingActivity.this);

    recyclerView.setAdapter(usersAdapter);
}
```

What should be done instead is the following:

1. Clear `mListe` from any previous content;
2. Fill with new content;
3. Set new data to the adapter.

```
if (response.isSuccessful()){
    mListe.clear();
    mListe.addAll(response.body());
    
    usersAdapter.setData(mListe);
}
```

I have removed a few lines from this if-statement and moved them into the `onCreate`. They should be called only once, there is no benefit setting the same adapter and click listener if you call `fetchUsers()` again.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...

    usersAdapter = new UsersAdapter();
    usersAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(usersAdapter);
 
    fetchUsers();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not adding anything in `ArrayList<User> mListe = new ArrayList<>();`

you should add values before implementing any action,

try this

```
if (response.isSuccessful()){
                List<User> users = response.body();
                mListe.addAll(users);
                usersAdapter.setData(users);
                usersAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(ScrollingActivity.this);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(usersAdapter);
            }
```